# Error downloading file requiring token with cURL

Tags: curl, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download an .aac audio file from Firebase Storage via cURL, using a generated public link.

If I paste the URL into a web browser, the file plays correctly in the browser. But if I download it with either of these commands:

```
curl -O https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<PROJECT_NAME>.appspot.com/o/<FILE_NAME>.aac?alt=media&token=<TOKEN>

curl -O https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<PROJECT_NAME>.appspot.com/o/<FILE_NAME>.aac -H "Authorization: <TOKEN>"
```

it downloads a file containing the text:

> {   "error": {
>       "code": 403,
>       "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"   } }

Is there another way I can pass the token and download the file?

Comment: Likely there are also some authorization cookies in your browser, so you don't see them in the URL. You should check the Request-headers in DevTools for such cookies. You can also simply copy the request as curl to include everything your browser sends, including cookies: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/replay-a-network-request-in-curl

Comment: @TobiasK Thanks for the suggestion! I copied the request as curl, adding the -O flag, and now it simply downloads an empty file. This is the full request as copied in devtools: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yHVVVCGF). Any other ideas?

Comment: Add `-i` to make curl dump everything including the headers, maybe there is a hint.

Comment: @TobiasK This dumps a file containing [this](https://pastebin.com/GbYc8pJP) output. 304 instead of 403, but still no data. If you're willing to explore further, I'd be happy to share a live link privately. Otherwise, open for other suggestions.

Comment: 304 means the server does not send the file because it was not modified since you last requested it. It determines that because your request includes `If-Modified-Since: Sat, 18 Aug 2018 17:54:48 GMT`. I have a really good feeling if you just remove that header it will work :)

Comment: @TobiasK Wow. I whittled away at the headers (removing `If-Modified-Since` still returned a 304) and eventually got down to `curl -O '<URL>'`, which worked. Turns out the only difference was quotes around the URL - no quotes fails, quotes succeeds. Thanks for setting me on the right track for figuring this out!